# Why conversion from Gridview to datatable fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to convert GRIDVIEW to DataTable but it doesn't give me data, it only gives me HEADERS of GridView but not the data inside it. Why ? I am using template fields in gridview

Calling it from event:

```
 DataTable dt = GetDataTable(GridView DenominationsWiseTransactions);
```

Conversion function:

```
DataTable GetDataTable(GridView dtg)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // add the columns to the datatable            
        if (dtg.HeaderRow != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dtg.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dtg.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
            }
        }

        //  add each of the data rows to the table
        foreach (GridViewRow row in dtg.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace(" ", "");
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us more code for context? How are you binding the data to the gridview? Which event are you using when you call `GetDataTable`?

Comment: ok wait i am pasting

Comment: How does your `GridView` look like and what is it's `DataSource`? If you use `TemplateFields` that doesn't work so anyway.

Comment: is there data / rows in dtg.Rows? have you debugged that?

Comment: i am using templated and boundfield in gridview

Comment: Why are you doing this anyways? GridView is a UI mechanism. You should grab the data table at the point you bind it to the grid view.

Comment: @Covert: then you don't get it in this way. A templatefield does not store it's content as `Text` in the cell. You need to use `FindControl("ID")` to get a reference to the desired control  in it. As an aside, why do you store the datatable in `ViewState`? You could use the `Session` if you really need but not the viewstate. That blows your traffic, everything  is written to the `input` which stores all the viewstate. Of course it should also not contain sensitive data since the client can read it.

Comment: ok sir, but the thing is that i cannot find any way to convert girdview to datatable, help me with this please @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Covert: but if you use controls in a `TemplateField`, how do you want to extract the text? You could even nest a `GridView` in a `GridView`, what do you expect as result from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you are looping through the rows in the datagrid, it will include headers, the rows and the footer.

To see just the data rows you need to do something like:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { //convert that row }
```

Your conversion line might need some work, but at least you'll only need to concern yourself with datarows now.